# How to regroup consecutive free timeslots

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm making the API of a MERN Stack and I struggle on an important route.

Here is an exemple of free slots I return.

```
[
  {
    booked: false,
    startAt: 2025-03-03T07:00:00.000Z,
    endAt: 2025-03-03T07:15:00.000Z,
  },
  {
    booked: false,
    startAt: 2025-03-03T07:15:00.000Z,
    endAt: 2025-03-03T07:30:00.000Z,

  },
  {
    booked: false,
    startAt: 2025-03-03T07:45:00.000Z,
    endAt: 2025-03-03T08:00:00.000Z,
  },
  {
    booked: false,
    startAt: 2025-03-03T08:00:00.000Z,
    endAt: 2025-03-03T08:15:00.000Z,
  },
  {
    booked: false,
    startAt: 2025-03-03T08:15:00.000Z,
    endAt: 2025-03-03T08:30:00.000Z,
  
  },
  {
    booked: false,
    startAt: 2025-03-03T10:15:00.000Z,
    endAt: 2025-03-03T10:30:00.000Z,
  
  },
  {
    booked: false,
    startAt: 2025-03-03T10:30:00.000Z,
    endAt: 2025-03-03T10:45:00.000Z,
  
  }
]
```

And want to regroup them by 2 or 3 consecutive slots like:

```
//Grouped by 2 with slot3 booked
[[slot1, slot2],[slot4,slot5],[slot5,slot6]]

//Grouped by 3 with all slots free
[[slot1, slot2,slot3],[slot2, slot3,slot4],[slot3, slot4,slot5],[slot4,slot5,slot6]]
```

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: I think we need more information.  Does your output combine them into single slots, for instance in your first output, is there just a single slot, 7:00 - 7: 30?  Or is there an array containing the two slots?  Also is your input guaranteed to be in order, and are all time periods covered or could there be times without slots?

Comment: Also why does slot5 show up twice in the first example?

Comment: I dont want to combine them I want to regroup them into arrays.

Yes guaranteed to be ordered and yeah ofc there is some times without since my output is the free slots. So if someone book a slot, he isn't available anymore.

The slot 5 is there twice cause 1 slot is the minimum service duration. So between like 08:00 and 09:00, if i have to book 45 min, I can book 08:00 to 08:45 OR 08:15 to 09:00

Comment: I'm starting to get it, but why do you not also have `[slot2, slot3, slot4]` and `[slot3, slot4, slot5]` in your second output?  Shouldn't you also be able to book `7:30 - 8:15` and `7:45 - 8:30`?

Comment: Yeah a mistake from me sorry :)

Comment: Added a "hole" of timeslot in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is almost certainly a slightly more efficient way of doing this with `reduce`, but this version is quite simple and likely performant enough for most reasonable cases:

```js
// utility function
const aperture = (n) => (xs) =>
  [...xs .keys ()] .slice (0, 1 - n) .map (i => xs .slice (i, i + n))


// main function
const groupSlots = (n, slots) => 
  aperture (n) (slots) .filter (group => group .every (({booked}) => ! booked))


// just to format output
const display = (o) => console .log (JSON.stringify (o, null, 4))

// sample data
const sixSlotsThirdBooked = [{booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T07:00:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T07:15:00.000Z'}, {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T07:15:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T07:30:00.000Z'}, {booked: true, startAt: '2025-03-03T07:45:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T08:00:00.000Z'}, {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T08:00:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T08:15:00.000Z'}, {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T08:15:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T08:30:00.000Z'}, {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T08:30:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T08:45:00.000Z'}]
// demo
display (groupSlots (2, sixSlotsThirdBooked))

// sample data
const sixFreeSlots = [{booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T07:00:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T07:15:00.000Z'}, {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T07:15:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T07:30:00.000Z'}, {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T07:45:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T08:00:00.000Z'}, {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T08:00:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T08:15:00.000Z'}, {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T08:15:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T08:30:00.000Z'}, {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T08:30:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T08:45:00.000Z'}]
// demo
display (groupSlots (3, sixFreeSlots))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The helper function **`aperture (n)`** moves a sliding window of length `n` along your data, so that, for instance, `aperture (2) (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])` would yield `[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'd']]`.

The main function, **`groupSlots`**, calls `aperture` on your input array of slots, then filters out those groups that have any booked slots.

(We also include a simple **`display`** function to skirt the slightly odd format that StackOverflow introduces to describe objects that contain multiple references to certain values.  But this is just a minor formatting bit.)

### Update

After an additional requirement (please note that I did ask that question in my initial comment on the post!), we can do this much the same way, but we need additional helper functions to restrict our work to contiguous blocks:

```js
// utility functions
const aperture = (n) => (xs) =>
  [...xs .keys ()] .slice (0, 1 - n) .map (i => xs.slice(i, i + n))

const last = (xs) =>
  xs [xs .length - 1]

const groupWith = (fn) => (xs) =>
  xs .reduce (
    (r, x, i, a) => i == 0 
      ? [[x]]
    : fn (last (last (r)), x)
      ? [... r .slice (0, -1), [... last (r), x]]
    : [...r, [x]],
    []
  )


// main function
const groupSlots = (n, slots) => 
  groupWith (({endAt}, {startAt}) => endAt == startAt) (slots .filter (({booked}) => ! booked)) 
    .flatMap (
      group => aperture (n) (group) 
    )
    
    
// just to format output
const display = (o) => console .log (JSON.stringify (o, null, 4))
    

// sample data
const slotsWithBreaks = [
  {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T07:00:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T07:15:00.000Z'}, 
  {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T07:15:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T07:30:00.000Z'}, 
  {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T07:30:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T07:45:00.000Z'}, 
  {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T07:45:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T08:00:00.000Z'}, 
  {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T08:00:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T08:15:00.000Z'}, 
  {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T08:15:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T08:30:00.000Z'}, 
  {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T08:30:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T08:45:00.000Z'},
  /* ... coffee break ...*/
  {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T09:00:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T09:15:00.000Z'},
  {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T09:15:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T09:30:00.000Z'},
  {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T09:30:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T09:45:00.000Z'},
  {booked: true,  startAt: '2025-03-03T09:45:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T10:00:00.000Z'},
  /* ... weekly meeting ... */
  {booked: true,  startAt: '2025-03-03T11:00:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T11:15:00.000Z'},
  {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T11:15:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T11:30:00.000Z'},
  {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T11:30:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T11:45:00.000Z'},
  {booked: false, startAt: '2025-03-03T11:45:00.000Z', endAt: '2025-03-03T12:00:00.000Z'},  
  /* ... lunch ... */
  // ...
]

// demo
display (groupSlots (3, slotsWithBreaks))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We add the trivial utility function, **`last`**, which returns the last element in an array.  We use `last` inside **`groupWith`**, which takes a predicate and returns a function which groups together elements of an array based on whether the predicate returns `true` when supplied two consecutive array elements.

We then update our main function to break the timeslots into contiguous arrays of (unbooked) slots, and call `aperture` on those, flat mapping the results into a single array.  Note that since we already had to break our output array apart based on unbookable slots, it's easiest to simply remove the booked slots up front, rather than use the check in the earlier version that all slots in a group were actually not booked.

I'm not thrilled with this implementation of `groupWith` and think there's probably something more elegant.  But I think it will do the job.

Comment: Thank you!

Is there a way to check if each element has the same date"endDate" than the next element's date "startDate".

Sorry if i wasn't clear enough but it might have no timeslot between 2 slots

Comment: @Gouze: Added an update which handles that.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you so much!